# LinkedList(T) add-method

Tags: .net, interface, explicit-interface

The Add-method from the [ICollection(T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13.aspx) interface has been explicitly implemented by the [LinkedList(T)-](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx)class. This collection instead have AddFirst- and AddLast-methods (among others). The explicitly implemented method maps to the AddLast-method. This has some drawbacks and IMHO no benefit at all. The two major drawbacks are this:

1. You can't use collection initialization on a LinkedList(T) since it requires an Add-method.
2. If you have used let's say a List(T) in a method and want to change it to use a LinkedList(T) instead you'll have to update all calls to Add to call AddLast instead.

The way I think about it is that you should **never** explicitly implement interface members unless they make no sense at all when you know the concrete type. For example the Add-method should be explicitly implemented (and effectively hidden) if you were implementing a read only ICollection(T).

Are there other examples of methods that have been explicitly implemented that shouldn't have been in the framework?

As a side note: To resolve the number 2 issue you could create an extension method "Add" for the LinkedList(T)-class.

Answer (score 4):

The `Add` method would be ambiguous, so I'm content with an explicit implementation...

`Queue[<T>]` and `Stack[<T>]` have similar behaviour.

For other (non-collection) curious explicit members - how about [`DbParameter.Precision`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357455.aspx) and [`DbParameter.Scale`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb346921.aspx).

Re the issue transferring between the two - you could always write a `ToLinkedList<T>` extension method on `IEnumerable<T>`.

Alternatively - an `AddRange<T>` extension method goes a long way...

```
static void Main()
{
    var list = new LinkedList<int>();
    list.AddRange(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
}
static void AddRange<T>(this ICollection<T> list, params T[] values)
{
    foreach (T value in values)
    {
        list.Add(value);
    }
}
```

(**EDIT**) You could also use a "fluent" API if you want to be able to use it as a single expression:

```
static void Main()
{
    var list = new LinkedList<int>().AddRange(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    // `list` is correctly a LinkedList<int> here
}
static TCollection AddRange<TCollection, TValue>(
    this TCollection collection, params TValue[] values)
    where TCollection : ICollection<TValue>
{
    foreach (TValue value in values)
    {
        collection.Add(value);
    }
    return collection;
}
```

Comment: I guess you mean that it would be ambiguous to the developer? The problem isn't that you can't add a range, the problem is that the interface differs from other ICollections so that they are not interchangeable unless cast to the interface.

Comment: Which is largely why interfaces exist... add to that list Queue and Stack, for example.

Comment: Queues and stacks aren't semantically comparable to simple collections. The same thing could more elegantly be accomplished with the EditorBrowsableAttribute.

Comment: I was not aware of the explicit implementation of Precision and Scale, interesting.